# How do you format an html tag within append using Jekyll / Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm looking to append an html anchor to the end of a string after splitting the string.

My existing code is

```
{{ post.content | split:'<!--excerpt-->' | first }}
```

So I'd like to add an append at the end of this

```
{{ post.content | split:'<!--excerpt-->' | first | append: 'ANCHOR HERE' }}
```

The anchor needs to include variables from the `post` object, and this in it's self needs to have some filtering applied.

So if I was just to write out what I wanted and it magically work, it would be

```
{{ post.content | split:'<!--excerpt-->' | first | append: '<a href="{{ post.url | remove:'.html' | append:'#more' }}">Read more...</a>' }}
```

However this doesn't work.

I've attempted to create a variable and do the formatting in that, but again can't seem to find a way via the official Liquid documents.

```
{% assign link = '<a href="' + post.url + '">Read more...</a>' %}
{{ post.content | split:'<!--excerpt-->' | first | append: link }}
```

Again this doesn't work.

Any help would be most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to create a variable is right, you just need to concat strings with [append](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/append/) filter:

```
{% assign link = '<a href="' | append: post.url | append: '">Read more...</a>' %}
```